# htaccess Change rewrite rules to override WP multisite for common specific folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-ini

I have several hosted clients and several subdomain clients, and I'd like to write *.htaccess* or *php.ini* rules to allow each of these sites, including my root site to have access to a common folder (/home/usr/public_html/public_scripts/) public that **the clients** (/home/usr/public_html/subdomains/client/) or (/home/usr/public_html/hosts/clients/) cannot see in ftp, but the root site can:

```
/home/usr
    |--/public_html
        |--/public_scripts/
        |
        |--/hosts
        |    |--/client
        |        |--/subdomains
        |
        |--/subdomains
            |--client
```

So that I can use this folder from:

```
www.mydomain.com/public_scripts/
subdomain.mydomain.com/public_scripts/
www.theirdomain.com/public_scripts/
subdomain.theirdomain.com/public_scripts/
```

I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ /home/usr/public_html/public_scripts/$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But this did not work. It simply redirects to `/index.php`

Shared hosting, so I do not have access to the httpd-conf file. I do have access to php.ini

it is matching correctly when I turn the WP rules off. I have both subdomain and domain mapping in my site, but I'm not sure if I need wp both sections or if I can combine all three into one rewrite rule.

Edit: Here's the rewrite rules I'm using, now that I realized I'm on a wordpress HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# BEGIN Wordpress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END Wordpress
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ /home/usr/public_html/public_scripts/$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-apple-aspen-config .mobileconfig
```

But this did not work. It simply redirects to `/index.php`

Shared hosting, so I do not have access to the httpd-conf file. I do have access to php.ini

It is matching correctly when I turn the WP rules off. I have both subdomain and domain mapping in my site, but I'm not sure if I need wp both sections or if I can combine all three into one rewrite rule.

Here's the "working" htaccess. Some day I'll have to organize these when I have more time:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# BEGIN Wordpress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END Wordpress
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ /home/usr/public_html/public_scripts/$1 [QSA]

# BEGIN WORDPRESS
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WORDPRESS
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-apple-aspen-config .mobileconfig
```

Comment: Why does it redirect to `index.php`? Are there other rewrite rules?

Comment: That, sir, is a great question. I completely forgot that have a Wordpress Multisite installation, and it is set to strip and rewrite for subdomains to redirect to index.php, because these are subdomains with their own document root folder. So the real question should be, "How do I override the default Multisite rewrite to include a common folder?" /facepalm

Comment: Can you ensure your rule is matched first?

Comment: I'll disable the wp rewrite and respond shortly with an answer to that

Comment: @Halcyon, it did match correctly. I posted the total htaccess file above.

Comment: Seems like this rule is a catch all: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`. It will matching anything. Move your rule up.

Comment: @Halcyon Fixed, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this rule is a catch all: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`. It will matching anything. Move your rule up.